# children in a mongoose schema wont save incremented numbers but only once

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user schema and I am able to increment the number and save to DB, but for children of the schema within an array I am also able to increment the number but it wont save to DB.

```
 const userSchema = new Schema({
        inDex: {type: Number, default: 0},
        userName: {
            type: String,
            require: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            lowercase: true,
            unique: false,
        },
        password: { type: String, required: true },
        mnemonic: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        profiles: [address: {index: {type: Number, default: 0}]
    })

    const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

    async function processUserInput(req, res) {


        User.findById({ _id: userId}).then((doc)=> {
            doc.inDex = doc.inDex+1   // Will Increment and Save
            doc.profiles[0].address.index = 
            doc.profiles[0].address.index+1   //Will increment BUT WONT SAVE

            doc.save()
        }).catch(err => console.log('err', err))

    }

    router.post('/',  async (req, res) => {
      await processUserInput(req,res)

      res.status(200).json(some json data)
    })
```

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-save `Document.prototype.save()` returns a promise, that promise should be returned from your promise handler function, so `doc.save()` -> `return doc.save()`

Comment: also your `processUserInput` function should return a promise, so add a `return` statement before `User.findById` https://javascript.info/async-await